# how to balance them for mutiple addresses for spring rabbitmq

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

I have a cluster of rabbitmqs. And configure the spring.rabbitmq.address=xxx,yyy,cccc

Then I start two consumer clients. The question is that the clients only connect one node, there,s not connection to the other nodes. I trace the codes, and found that :

```
public Connection newConnection(ExecutorService executor, AddressResolver addressResolver, String clientProvidedName) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    if (this.metricsCollector == null) {
        this.metricsCollector = new NoOpMetricsCollector();
    }

    FrameHandlerFactory fhFactory = this.createFrameHandlerFactory();
    ConnectionParams params = this.params(executor);
    if (clientProvidedName != null) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new 
        HashMap(params.getClientProperties());
        properties.put("connection_name", clientProvidedName);
        params.setClientProperties(properties);
    }

    if (this.isAutomaticRecoveryEnabled()) {
        AutorecoveringConnection conn = new AutorecoveringConnection(params, 
            fhFactory, addressResolver, this.metricsCollector);
        conn.init();
        return conn;
    } else {
        List<Address> addrs = addressResolver.getAddresses();
        Exception lastException = null;
        Iterator var8 = addrs.iterator();

        while(var8.hasNext()) {
            Address addr = (Address)var8.next();

            try {
                **FrameHandler handler = fhFactory.create(addr);
                AMQConnection conn = this.createConnection(params, handler, this.metricsCollector);
                conn.start();
                this.metricsCollector.newConnection(conn);
                return conn;**
            } catch (IOException var12) {
                lastException = var12;
            } catch (TimeoutException var13) {
                lastException = var13;
            }
        }

        if (lastException != null) {
            if (lastException instanceof IOException) {
                throw (IOException)lastException;
            }

            if (lastException instanceof TimeoutException) {
                throw (TimeoutException)lastException;
            }
        }

        throw new IOException("failed to connect");
    }
}
```

We can see that it creates one connection then returned. But if I wanna the other consumer client can connect to the left nodes instead the same node, although both of the consumer clients have the same configuration:

spring:
rabbitmq:
username: aaaa
password: aaaa
virtual-host: /
addresses: xxxx:5672,yyy:5672,zzzzz:5672
listener:
simple:
concurrency: 4
max-concurrency: 4
prefetch: 4
What should I do ？ can someone give some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try rotating the list of addresses in each client's configuration:

- First - xxxx:5672,yyy:5672,zzzzz:5672
- Second - yyy:5672,zzzzz:5672,xxxx:5672
- Third - zzzzz:5672,xxxx:5672,yyy:5672

Comment: If there are many clients, it's not a good way to solve the problem. And difficult to maintain the configuration.

Comment: Well, it is what it is. It looks like the [current code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/AbstractConnectionFactory.java#L440-L478) passes the list of addresses to the RabbitMQ Java client [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.java#L827-L848). Both sets of code are open-source, so you could provide a pull request that implements a round-robin or random `AddressResolver`.